# The brush menu shrunk, how to do i fix it?

Tags: interface

What the Title Said it just got really small I must have shrunk it by accident but idk what I hit.
[image: It just got really small I must have shrunk it by accident but idk what I hit.]

Answer (score 0):

Just hover over the menu and use <kbd>Scroll Wheel</kbd>to zoom.